# Add SearchBar in Navigation Page in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am following these tutorials to implement `Searchbar` in `NavigationPage` in **Xamarin.Forms**:

- [Searchbar in Navigation bar Or TabbedPage](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/39690/searchbar-in-navigation-bar-or-tabbedpage)
- [How to add search bar in navigation bar in Xamarin forms](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/104707/how-to-add-search-bar-in-navigation-bar-in-xamarin-forms)
- [A iOS and Android app to monitor the views and clones of your GitHub repos](https://github.com/brminnick/GitTrends)
- [Xamarin Forms - ContentPage with SearchBar in the Navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50287223/xamarin-forms-contentpage-with-searchbar-in-the-navigation-bar) .

I have a simple `ContentPage` which I open in *App.cs* In `NavigationPage` form:

```
var navigationPage = new Xamarin.Forms.NavigationPage(new Home());
navigationPage.On<iOS>().SetPrefersLargeTitles(true);
MainPage = navigationPage;
```

While running the project I get error in **Renderer** **Page** in the following line:

```
Toolbar GetToolbar() => CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

the exception thrown is:

> System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to convert instance of type 'Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar' to type 'Android.Widget.Toolbar'.'

I can't figure out why this error appears, although it shows that it has problem in casting.

Does anyone see where is my error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

Change your line with error to

```
var toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

### Explanation

Even though it is not clear with the piece of code you shared, it seems that your Renderer **Class** is `using Android.Widget`, which also defines a `Toolbar` member and might be conflicting with the return value of `FindViewById` which is `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar`.

So, now that the fix is explained, i would add that a better way to fix your problem is either removing the `using Android.Widget` and add instead `using Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` so you can write code like

```
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
...

// This Toolbar refers to the one in V7!
Toolbar toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```

or if you still need `using Android.Widget`, then you could use an alias:

```
using Android.Widget;
using V7Toolbar = Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar;
...

// This Toolbar refers to the one in V7!
V7Toolbar toolbar = CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity.FindViewById<V7Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
```